# Can't creating web service from WSDL (netbeans: There is no service in specified WSDL file.)

Tags: java, netbeans, wsdl, xmlspy

I created WSDL file in Altora XMLSpay and I whant created Web service in Netbeans (Web servicies from WSDL...) but always when add .wsdl file Netbeans write that "There is no service in specified WSDL file." Can you help me? What's wrong with my wsdl documnet?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://new.webservice.namespace" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified"/>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="NewMessageRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" type="xs:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="NewMessageResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" type="xs:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="GetDbStatus">
        <wsdl:operation name="OpenDB">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:NewMessageRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:NewMessageResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="GetDbStatusBinding" type="tns:GetDbStatus">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="OpenDB">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:#NewOperation"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="Test_Wsdl">
        <wsdl:port name="GetDbstatusPort" binding="tns:GetDbStatusBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/mpo_getdbstatus/GetDbStatus"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in your wsdl

GetDbStatusBinding
The part of the message 'NewMessageRequest' references a schema type instead of a schema element.
The part of the message 'NewMessageResponse' references a schema type instead of a schema element.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me but I have another error:
[ERROR] Schema descriptor {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string in message part "messageReq" is not defined and could not be bound to Java. Perhaps the schema descriptor {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string is not defined in the schema imported/included in the WSDL. You can either add such imports/includes or run wsimport and provide the schema location using -b switch.
  line 8 of file:/C:/.../.../mpo_getdbstatus/src/conf/xml-resources/web-services/NewWebServiceFromWSDL/wsdl/mpo_getdbstatus_wsdl.wsdl

C:......\mpo_getdbstatus\nbproject\jaxws-build.xml:31: Error starting wsimport: null

```
   <wsimport sourcedestdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/service/NewWebServiceFromWSDL" destdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/service/NewWebServiceFromWSDL" wsdl="${basedir}/${conf-dir}xml-resources/web-services/NewWebServiceFromWSDL/wsdl/mpo_getdbstatus_wsdl.wsdl" catalog="catalog.xml" encoding="${source.encoding}" extension="true" verbose="true" fork="false" xnocompile="true" xendorsed="true">
            <depends file="${basedir}/${conf-dir}xml-resources/web-services/NewWebServiceFromWSDL/wsdl/mpo_getdbstatus_wsdl.wsdl"/>
            <produces dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/service/NewWebServiceFromWSDL"/>
        </wsimport>
```